# java, generic and getAll

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to modify my code to avoid all the duplicate code, using generic.

I have a class DBBaseClass wich will be extended by some other class. I'm trying to create a getAll method that return all the object of the subclass stored in a database.

```
 class abstract DBBaseClass {

  abstract readDataBase(int _id);

  public  <T extends DBBaseClass> List<T> getAll()
  {

 List<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();    

 ArrayList<Integer> myints = DBManager.request_database_for_ids(getIdField(), getTableName());

 T myTObject = new T();    // NOT WORKING  *************************

 for (int i=0;i<myints.size();i++) {        
        myTObject.read(myints.get(i));
        array.add(myTObject);
    }               

return array;
```

I have the errors :
    - Cannot instantiate the type T
    - The type T is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with 
     arguments <>

How can i instanciate my T subclass here ??

**What's the trick ??**

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

To explain more in details my goal :
I have two classes SUbClassA and SubClassB that extends DBBaseClass.

I want to a method :
SubClassA.getAll() that returns an arraylist of SUbClassA objects.
SubClassB.getAll() that returns an arraylist of SUbClassB objects.

At first, i created getAll in all my subClasses  ... So, I'm trying now  to put this getAll() in the DBBaseclass.

It's easy to do if i want them to return List but i don't know how to tell the method "return me a list of this particular kind of subclass".

Comment: Do you want the DBBase Class to contain instances of itself? That looks quite strange to me. Please explain, as if we were 9 year old children, what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only can instantiate a concret class but not `T` as it is only a type and not `DBBaseClass` as it is abstract.

What could you do:

- Define a concrete class extending `DBBaseClass` such as `SubDBBaseClass`
- Create a factory method for each sub-class that returns a concrete instance such as

  ```
  protected T create() {
      return new SubDBBaseClass();
  }
  ```
- Invoke this method in your `DBBaseClass.getAll()` method such as

  ```
  T myTObject = create();
  ```

Perhaps you didn't know, but your are using the [active record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) that has its ups and downs. I don't like the pattern and I would redesign the architecture. But these are only my 5 cents.

Comment: Thanks it's working. I'm actually redesigning the architecture as at first, when i started my project, i had very poor OOP knowledge. So, i would be happy to have some clues on how to redesign the architecture. I've heard about the factory pattern. Not sure if it would work here.

Comment: Have a look at the excellent book "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture" by Martin Fowler giving an overview about service architecture.

Answer (score 2):

You want to make DBBaseClass generic, for that declare it like this:

```
abstract class DBBaseClass<T extends DBBaseClass<?>>
```

Comment: Look here for more information about generics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: updated to enable extensions of generic type and fixed abstract position